# How to call functions from file?

Tags: javascript, html

I´m new to JS, and I'm trying to use these polynomial functions from the file `polynomial.js` on this page https://github.com/infusion/Polynomial.js

If I copy and paste in node js terminal the whole script of `polynomial.js`, I'm able to run the examples on that page, for example

```
**Adding two polynomials**
var p = new Polynomial("3x^2").add("-x^2"); // 2x^2

**Second derivative of polynomial**
var p = new Polynomial("5+3x^3+6x^5").derive(2); // 120x^3+18x
```

Now, having an HTML index file (with its CSS), I'm referencing the `polynomial.js` within `<script></script>` tags but I'm not getting any answer
when I try to sum 2 polynomials by clicking on the button.

How to do it correctly to able able to call any function from `polynomial.js` and see the result in HMTL?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Calculate</h1>
  <div>
    <label for="pol1">Polynomial 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pol1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="pol2">Polynomial 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pol2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="add">Add 2 Polynomial</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="result">Result:</label>
    <input type="text" id="result" readonly>
  </div>

  <script src="polynomial.js">
    var pol1 = document.getElementById('pol1').value;
    var pol2 = document.getElementById('pol2').value;

    var result = Polynomial(pol1).add(pol2);
    document.getElementById('result').value = result;
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The `<script>` tag either has a `src` attribute or contents, but not both. You need two script tags, i.e. `<script src="polynomial.js"></script><script> // your custom code here </script>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´ve followed your suggestion and still don´t get any answer when I click the button.

Comment: `onclick="add"` is also wishful thinking. You need an eventListener: Add id to the button: `<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>` then change your script to `document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", () => {
    var pol1 = document.getElementById('pol1').value;
    var pol2 = document.getElementById('pol2').value;

    var result = Polynomial(pol1).add(pol2);
    document.getElementById('result').value = result; });`

Comment: Also you need to download the https://github.com/infusion/Polynomial.js/blob/master/polynomial.min.js and save it. If you save the file in the same folder as the html, then you need `<script src="polynomial.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use external and internal scripts in the same tag as you are doing here. Separate those into two different `script` tags. Also, Github has some security check that stops browser from using files as intended(some browsers/applications may support it). Hence, in order to use this **github** file directly through a link, you need to use this link `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/infusion/Polynomial.js@master/polynomial.min.js` . Please note that the `Polynomial` does not take **UpperCase letters** and gives zero as a result. you need to convert each input to `lowerCase` so as to avoid any issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/infusion/Polynomial.js@master/polynomial.min.js">
    </script>
    
    <script>
        const a = new Polynomial("x^2").toLowerCase();
        const b = new Polynomial("2x^2").toLowerCase();
        const c = a.add(b);
        const sum = new Polynomial(c);
        console.log(sum.toString());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a sample code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lepm6nft/4/

Comment: Polynomial.js is not an esm module therefore this answer is wrong. It adds the `Ploynomial` class directly to the document by doing `window.Polynomial = Polynomial`. Therefore you shouldn't/can't import the file.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but doesn't work.

Comment: I paste your code in a file or in JSFiddle and simply doesn´t show any output. Does it work for you?

Comment: The Polynomial.js doesn't recognize upperCase characters and gives zero as a result. keep  that in mind. You have to convert all input to lowercase.

Comment: Thank you. You were right. It was the lower case thing. Now it seems to work fine your example.

Comment: Please note the github file usage comment in the answer as well. You can not link any respository directly from github. If you don't want to download the file, you can use this link https://www.jsdelivr.com/github to get any github repository from jsdelievr's CDN.